# pandas_read.excel() not able to read non-English characters

Tags: python, excel, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I've been trying to use read a .xlsx file using pandas.read_excel, but the output only shows a question mark in the place of non-English characters like í.

I've tried:

```
df = pandas.read_excel(u"C:\MyFile.xlsx")
```

and

```
df = pandas.read_excel("C:\MyFile.xlsx", encoding='utf-8')
```

I also tried other encoding formats like utf-16,utf-32, utf-8-sig, iso-8859-1, etc. None of these seem to work.

Kindly help.

**UPDATE: It works perfectly on cmd, but not when i run it using visual studio code. In cmd, BeautifulSoup is giving a similar error for the html file which works fine on visual studio!**

Comment: All of the codes you tried worked for me

Comment: What do you think might be my error then?

Comment: Is your interpreter configured to UTF-8? ( `# coding: utf-8`
). Or your command line prompt?

Comment: Can you share input files or what kind of non-ascii chars or languages were being used?

Comment: Please check my updated edit.

Comment: @Mika72, please check the updated edit. I think it's the problem with the interpreter. What can be done about this?